# Confusion about Lie groups in Fulton & Harris

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Near the beginning of chapter 8 (titled Lie groups and Lie algebras) authors motivate the definition of Lie algebra. I’m confused by two things in just one sentence:

($G$ is a Lie group)

> The group $\operatorname{Aut} T_e G$ being just an open subset of the vector space of endomorphisms $\operatorname{End} T_e G$, its tangent space at the identity is naturally identified with $\operatorname{End} T_e G$.

First: How do we get the topology on $\operatorname{End} T_e G$?
Is it just that $\operatorname{End} T_e G$ is (by a choice of basis) isomorphic to $M_n \mathbb R$ and we can identify $M_n \mathbb R$ with $R^{n^2}$? Or we can do something similar without choice of basis?

Second: How do we “naturally identify” a tangent space at the identity of $\operatorname{End} T_e G$ with $\operatorname{End} T_e G$ itself?

Comment: The answer to your first question is yes. The space of linear maps gets its topology from any choice of basis for $T_eG$. For your second question: Given a point $p$ in a vector space $V$, any $v\in V$ gives a derivation at $p$ my sending a differentiable $f:V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ to $\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}(f(p+tv))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, any finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb R$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$ for some $n$ (by choosing a basis) so we just define that isomorphism to be a homeomorphism.  Then you check that linear maps on $\mathbb R^n$ are always continuous, hence vector space isomorphisms are always homeomorphisms, and this implies that the topology you get on $\mathrm{End}(T_eG)$ did not depend on your choice of isomorphisms $\mathrm{End}(T_eG) \simeq \mathbb M_n(\mathbb R) \simeq \mathbb R^{n^2}$.

So while you do define the topology using a basis, the result is independent of your choice of basis.

2. This depends largely on what specific definition you take for "tangent vectors" and "tangent spaces".  I don't have Fulton & Harris in front of me, but choosing a basis you have $\mathrm{End}(T_eG) \simeq \mathbb M_n(\mathbb R)$.  Any function $f\colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb M_n(\mathbb R)$ is given by component functions $f_{ij}\colon\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ where $f_{ij}(M)$ is the $(i, j)^\text{th}$ entry of the matrix $f(M)$.  Then $\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}t}$ is the matrix whose $(i, j)^\text{th}$ entry is $\frac{\mathrm{d}f_{ij}}{\mathrm{d}t}$.  In particular, $\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}t}(0)$ (which should be a tangent vector) is a matrix in $\mathbb M_n(\mathbb R) \simeq \mathrm{End}(T_eG)$.

Answer (score 1):

In $\mathbf{R}^n$ any open set has $\mathbf{R}^n$ as tangent space at any of its points. Automorphisms of $ \mathbf{R}^n$ is an open set in the collection of all endomorphisms.

Comment: @Rócherz I think your edit changed the meaning of a sentence this answer. Usually it  is not a good idea to do a bunch of small edits to old answers, and changing their meaning is an absolute no-no.

Comment: And, as far as I can tell, the original version is grammatically correct whereas you mangled it: *Automorphisms of $\mathbf{R}^n$* is a description of a subset of all endomorphisms, so it is singular. Arguably it might be better to phrase it *Automorphisms of $\mathbf{R}^n$ form an open set...*, but I trust P Vanhinathan's English over my own any day of the wekk.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts to weed out the  imperfection in my wording. I meant "the set of all automohisms is an open set in the set of all endomorphisms".

Comment: The second comment was still directed at the earlier editor, sorry about not making it clear. They were on an editing spree, but missed the boat here, thinking that there was a congruence error (given that they rephrased it something along the lines of *...Automorphisms are open sets...*, not realizing that the subject was singular. Anyway, it may be possible to improve the phrasing, but I trust your choice over mine :-)